# Is there a way to update composite template to add documents when some recipients already signed

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I created a DocuSign envelope with composite template containing some documents. The routing includes 3 signers. One has signed and now email would go to next signer in routing order. Is it possible, to add a new document in the composite template? Or simply attach the new document to email so the next signer will see this additional document as well.

I have used following API but no success.
PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}

```
{
  "status": "sent",
  "emailSubject": "Adding documents after first signer has signed",
  "documents": [{
    "documentId": "1",
    "name": "contract.pdf",
    "documentBase64": "don't want to convert to base64 ...",
  }],
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [{
      "name": "Tharak Padi",
      "email": "Tharak@email.com",
      "recipientId": "1",
      "routingOrder": "1",
      "tabs": {
        "signHereTabs": [{
          "xPosition": "150",
          "yPosition": "200",
          "documentId": "1",
          "pageNumber": "1"
        }],
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

When 2nd signer open the email link from DocuSign, he/she will see the new document

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do that using what is known as *Correct*.

That allows to modify an envelope after it was sent out.
more info - https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-correct-documents.

From API see - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/update

Comment: Thanks for you response Inbar Gazit. The API part 'signerAttachmentTabs' does not actually attach a document. It gives recipient flexibility to attach by providing file selection. What I am doing is, when first signer signs and hit FINISH, attach a pre-defined document. So the next recipient gets an updated envelope with a new document.
Yes. This will be marked CORRECTED and this second recipient will get 2 emails; one that there has been some correction and second to actually sign.

Comment: ok, you can also use an attachmentTab, but then the signer has to upload the document. It wasn't clear that's how you wish to add the new document.

Comment: then you need to use the correct. To know when the first signer signed - you can use Connect to get a webhook notification

Comment: Webhook currently not an option for us so we will be simply using DocuSign push notification. So let me refresh that a REST API is what I am looking to add a new document once 2nd recipient signs. This means that when DocuSign push notification arrives with <status>Completed</status>, call API and add the doc.
How can I use following API to pick a document from a shared folder

PUT /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}

Comment: the body is documented in https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/update just look for the documents section